# typescript synchronous function with import?

Tags: typescript

```
// addons.ts

export interface addon {
  name: string;
  desc: string;
  run: (someparam: any) => void;
}

export function loadaddons(): Array<addon> {
  let addons: Array<addon> = [];
  fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "addons"))
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"))
    .forEach((file) => {
      import(path.join(__dirname, "addons", file)).then((imported) => {
        addons.push({
          name: imported.addonInfo.name,
          desc: imported.addonInfo.desc,
          run: imported.startAddon,
        });
      });
    });
  return addons;
}


// index.ts

import { loadaddons } from "./addons";
let addons = loadaddons();
addons.forEach((addon) => {
  addon.run("someparam");
});


// example addon

export const addonInfo = {
  name: "exampleaddon",
  desc: "an example addon",
};

export function startAddon() {}


// output

[]


// wanted output

[
  {
    name: 'exampleaddon',
    desc: 'an example addon',
    run: [Function: startAddon]
  }
]
```

Issue is that the import() function is not sync and the function will not return when its done importing and adding all the addons to variable, yes i could do a return in the .after() but that would only work if there was a single addon, well this is not the case. await returns error and  i dont know how to proceed; how i want it to run:

- read directory
- filter files to .js
- cycle through (do not return until cycle is complete)

  - import
  - add info to addons var
- return addons variable

note: new to typescript

Comment: Try to use `require` instead of `import` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous functions in TypeScript are "contagious" in a sense: once you introduce an asynchronous section in a pipeline, you must almost always make the entire pipeline asynchronous as well. This is not all bad, since there are some decent tools for working with asynchronous functions.

Suppose you wish to modify your `loadaddons` function to be asynchronous. The first thing to consider is the type signature. Instead of returning a value of type `Array<addon>`, it will now return one of type `Promise<Array<addon>>`. So your new signature resembles:

```
function loadaddons(): Promise<Array<addon>> {
  // ... to be updated
}
```

Now, we need to modify the body of this function to perform asynchronously. You've written your function nicely as a "pipeline" of actions (*read*, then *filter*, then *act*, etc.), which makes it particularly straightforward to transform. Consider modifying the pipeline one section at a time.

We first need to replace `readdirSync` with `readdir`. Whereas `readdirSync` returns an `Array<string>`, `readdir` expects a function as its final argument; it calls this function with the array of filenames once they are ready. I'd rather work with promises than callbacks, and luckily it is easier enough to transform a function that expects a callback into one that returns a promise. All that is required is the [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function from the `'util'` module. That is, `promisify(readdir)(path.join(__dirname, 'addons'))` returns a promise, as desired.

Now we can't just call the `filter` method directly on the value returned by `promisify(readdir)`, since it's a promise and not a "regular" value. Pretty much all we can do with a `Promise` is provide a function *to be called on the value that the promise resolves to*. This involves entertaining the hypothetical "supposing this promise resolves to an array filenames named `fs`; what would I want to do with this array?". Here is how we answer it:

```
import { promisify } from 'util';

promisify(readdir)(path.join(__dirname, 'addons'))
  .then(fs => fs.filter(f => f.endsWith('.js')))
```

Now we're getting somewhere. This expression is a `Promise` that resolves to an array containing the filenames of all of the JavaScript files in the directory. All that is left to do is `import` these files and collect some information from them.

Let's imagine what is involved for doing this for a single file. Say its filename is `'my-file.js'`. We want to `import` it, and then produce an object that satisfies the `addon` interface. Since `import` produces a `Promise`, we will provide a function that answers the hypothetical "supposing this promise resolves to a JavaScript file named `contents`; how would I extract the data I need from it?". That might look like this:

```
import('my-file.js').then(contents => ({
  name: contents.addonInfo.name,
  desc: contents.addonInfo.desc,
  run: contents.startAddon
}));
```

Note that this expression is a `Promise<addon>`. We want to take an *Array* of these and produce a `Promise<Array<addon>>`. As it turns out, there is already a nifty function for doing such a thing! It is called [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), and it expects a value of type `Array<Promise<T>>` and produces a `Promise<Array<T>>`.

Here it is in action:

```
import { promisify } from 'util';

promisify(readdir)(path.join(__dirname, 'addons'))
  .then(fs => fs.filter(f => f.endsWith('.js')))
  .then(fs => Promise.all(fs.map(extractAddOn)));

function extractAddOn(filename: string): Promise<addon> {
  return import(filename).then(contents => ({
    name: contents.addonInfo.name,
    desc: contents.addonInfo.desc,
    run: contents.startAddon
  }));
}
```

That's it!

Now, a couple of improvements:

1. It is a convention to give interfaces names in PascalCase. This would involve renaming your `addon` interface to `AddOn` or `Addon`.
2. It's also a convention to give values (including functions) names in camelCase. This would involve renaming your `loadaddons` function to `loadAddOns` or `loadAddons`.
3. It's a convention (although less universal than the previous two) to use `T[]` to represent the type of "an array of values, each of which has type `T`", rather than `Array<T>`.

Applying these changes gets you here:

```
import { promisify } from 'util';

export interface AddOn {
  name: string;
  desc: string;
  run: (someParam: any) => void;
}

export function loadAddOns(): Promise<AddOn[]> {
  return promisify(readdir)(path.join(__dirname, 'addons'))
    .then(fs => fs.filter(f => f.endsWith('.js')))
    .then(fs => Promise.all(fs.map(extractAddOn)));
}

function extractAddOn(filename: string): Promise<AddOn> {
  return import(filename).then(contents => ({
    name: contents.addonInfo.name,
    desc: contents.addonInfo.desc,
    run: contents.startAddon
  }));
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i love you, thank you so much for such a detailed answer!!